# My TextInputEditText Isn't showing after Running my code

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Althought you can clearly see the how the design looks clearly fine, both TextInputEditText are visible but when i run the code TextInputEditText becomes totally invisible unless when i click on it, Also the TextView that says "Hello there, Welcome back" doesn't show

**Here is how my layout looks like before running it** :

[image]

**And that's how it looks after I run it** :
[image]

**my xml code** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".loginLast.LoginMainlast"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/univ2sticker"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logo_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello there, Welcome Back"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bungeeregular"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/slogan_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In to continue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:fontFamily="@font/anticregular"/>





    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/usernameLog"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/passwordLog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Password"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/loginBtnlog"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:text="GO"
            android:background="#000"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>




            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/signupBtn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="NEW USER? SIGN UP"
                android:fontFamily="@font/anticregular"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
               android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:elevation="0dp"/>



    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are using a material design component so check the theme used in the style.xml file and change your parent theme with `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: @Hey.Its_RJ yup mine is ```Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar ```

Comment: @Hey.Its_RJ and I just realised that my device was running with the dark mode activated that was the problem so thanks! if you want to put your comment as an answer so I can check it , thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You are using a material design component so check the theme used in the style.xml file and change your parent theme with `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`